min from columns from dict
I have a dict with item\column name and a df with columns from dict and other columns. How can I add column to df with min value for every item just from columns corresponding from dict?
import pandas as pd
my_dict={'Item1':['Col1','Col3'],
'Item2':['Col2','Col4']
        }
df=pd.DataFrame({
            'Col0':['Item1','Item2'],
            'Col1':[20,25],
            'Col2':[89,15],
            'Col3':[26,30],
            'Col4':[40,108],
            'Col5':[55,2]
            })
df['min']=?

I tried
df['min']=df[df.columns[df.columns.isin(my_dict)]].min(axis=1),

but it didn't work.

Can you have multiple times the same value in "Col0"?

No, values in "Col0" are unique

You can use apply with a function that reads the appropriate column names out of the dictionary (returning an empty list if there is no match) and then takes the minimum of the specified columns:
my_dict = {
    'Item1': ['Col1', 'Col3'],
    'Item2': ['Col2', 'Col4']
}

df['min'] = df.apply(lambda r:r[my_dict.get(r['Col0'], [])].min(), axis=1)

Output:
    Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  min
0  Item1    20    89    26    40    55   20
1  Item2    25    15    30   108     2   15

If it's possible my_dict may contain column names that don't exist in the dataframe, you can check for that in the function. For example:
my_dict = {
    'Item1': ['Col1', 'Col3'],
    'Item2': ['Col4', 'Col6']
}

df['min'] = df.apply(
    lambda r:r[[col for col in my_dict.get(r['Col0'], []) if col in r]].min(),
    axis=1
)

Output:
    Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  min
0  Item1    20    89    26    40    55   20
1  Item2    25    15    30   108     2  108

You can even get the column names if you want:
my_dict = {
    'Item1': ['Col1', 'Col3'],
    'Item2': ['Col2', 'Col4']
}

df[['min', 'name']] = df.apply(
    lambda r:min((r[col], col) for col in my_dict.get(r['Col0'], []) if col in r),
    axis=1, result_type='expand'
)

Output:
    Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  min  name
0  Item1    20    89    26    40    55   20  Col1
1  Item2    25    15    30   108     2   15  Col2


@Евгения no worries - I'm glad I could help

Can I ask one more question? What if columns in df not alwayas has all columns from dict (for example it doesn't has Col1? How to add .isin paramether?

@Евгения you could use df.apply(lambda r:r[[col for col in my_dict.get(r['Col0'], []) if col in r]].min(), axis=1)

@Евгения no worries

Is it possible to add a column with column names of this min values?

@Евгения yes... try df[['min', 'name']] = df.apply(lambda r:min((r[col], col) for col in my_dict.get(r['Col0'], []) if col in r), axis=1, result_type='expand')

Perfect! I added .dropna() and it works!

Great! I think you probably need to ask a new question next time though :)

You can use the dictionary to compute an existance table of Item and Col. Then use this table to mask the original dataframe.
my_dict = {
    'Item1':['Col1','Col3'],
    'Item2':['Col6','Col4']
}

m = pd.crosstab(*(pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
                  .stack().reset_index(level=1)
                  .T.to_numpy()))

df['min'] = df.set_index('Col0').where(m.eq(1), float('inf')).min(axis=1).to_list()

print(m)

col_0  Col1  Col3  Col4  Col6
row_0                        
Item1     1     1     0     0
Item2     0     0     1     1


print(df)

    Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5    min
0  Item1    20    89    26    40    55   20.0
1  Item2    25    15    30   108     2  108.0


Another approach using groupby.apply. This has the advantage of indexing all rows that share the same "Col0" value simultaneously if this value can be repeated.
df[['min', 'name']] = (df
   .assign(default=np.nan)
   .groupby('Col0', group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda x: x[my_dict.get(x.name, ['default'])]
                    .agg(['min', 'idxmin'], axis=1),
          include_groups=False)
)

Output:
    Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5 min  name
0  Item1    20    89    26    40    55  20  Col1
1  Item2    25    15    30   108     2  15  Col2


import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'Item1': ['Col1', 'Col3'],
           'Item2': ['Col2', 'Col4']}

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col0': ['Item1', 'Item2'],
    'Col1': [200, 25],
    'Col2': [8, 100],
    'Col3': [300, 30],
    'Col4': [40, 108],
    'Col5': [55, 2]
})

df['min'] = df.apply( lambda row : 
               row[dict1[row['Col0']]].min(),axis=1
)

'''
    Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  min
0  Item1   200     8   300    40    55  200
1  Item2    25   100    30   108     2  100
'''

